# How to send an image from desktop(client) to server & vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a web page, by clicking on a Button

1. a file browser dialog box opens (it should be able to access the client's system)
2. choose a `jpg/gif/any image file` and click OK to send
3. send it to server `via AJAX`
4. once the image saved in server, a confirm message appears and
5. save image populated on client machine in dialog/another window

No. 3,  4 can do using Ajax and server side programmimg (java),   but i am not very confident about 1, 2 & 5.
Please help...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1 & 2 Use an HTML input tag of type file: `<input type='file' id='uploadfile'>`. Alternativly if you don't mind using a little flash [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) is pretty cool. I', not sure what you mean by step 5. Do you want the uploaded image to be displayed somewhere on the active browser window?

Comment: Thanks Matro :) No.5 :Yes,  Once the image uploaded in server, then the image should pop up or appear in model dialog. BTW I'll resolve this.

Comment: Then you should use a callback to update the content of the container in the dialog. Uploadify has an oncomplete method you should look at if you go down that path: http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/events/oncomplete-2/

Comment: @matro: i just checked it and giving IO error. failed to upload any file, don't know why?

Comment: @user575363 checked what? You've not told us what you've done. Checked your webserver error log? what does Firebug say?

Answer (score 0):

1. A standard file input.
2. Better validate filetype on the server not client. You may use [`accept` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp), but there's no use from it in most browsers.
3. Use [ajaxupload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)
4. Send ajax response and handle it on the client side. Display the image in `img`, for example.
5. Not sure. Why do you want to save it when the user just uploaded it from his machine?

Comment: @Thanks Hnatt,I mean, Once image uploaded at server then it must be save somewhere in server, Right? after that  i want to display it in client's browser. BTW i can solve this part myself